# How to add two record for one item in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
Parent  date        currency_type   currency 
---------------------------------------------
4106    2016/06/11  EUR             3000.00 
2055    2017/06/10  USD             4000000.00  
2055    2017/06/10  EUR             4030000.00
```

How can I add one row like this code automatically if one type of usd or eur is null, I have two types usd and eur

```
4106    2016/06/11  USD             0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need UNION ALL, where the 2nd query will create these rows if they don't exist:

```
select * from tablename
union all
select 
  t.parent, 
  t.date,
  case t.currency_type
    when 'EUR' THEN 'USD'
    when 'USD' THEN 'EUR'
  end,
  0
from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where parent = t.parent and currency_type <> t.currency_type
) 
order by parent desc, currency_type
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=da583ee51d71c84f6c2a97e64fe276bf).
Results:

```
> Parent | date                | currency_type | currency
> -----: | :------------------ | :------------ | -------:
>   4106 | 11/06/2016 00:00:00 | EUR           |     3000
>   4106 | 11/06/2016 00:00:00 | USD           |        0
>   2055 | 10/06/2017 00:00:00 | EUR           |  4030000
>   2055 | 10/06/2017 00:00:00 | USD           |  4000000
```

Comment: thanks this code so easy to learn better fro me,because i  am noob in sql server

Comment: Note that this solution only handles two (hard-coded) currency types.

Comment: This is the requirement: *I have two types usd and eur*

Answer (score 1):

One option is to do an insert with a calendar table containing all parents, dates, and currency types:

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (Parent, date, currency_type, currency)
SELECT p.Parent, d.date, c.currency_type, 0
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Parent FROM yourTable) AS p
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT date FROM yourTable) AS d
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT currency_type FROM yourTable) AS c
LEFT JOIN yourTable t
    ON t.Parent = p.Parent AND
       t.date = d.date AND
       t.currency_type = c.currency_type
WHERE
    t.Parent IS NULL;
```

The series of cross joins generates all possible combinations of parents, dates, and currency types.  Then, the left anti join flushes out combinations which are missing in your current table.  This approach assumes that each possible parent, date, and currency type already exists at least once somewhere in your current table.  It would fail if, for example, you wanted to fill a date completely missing in your current table.  In that case, we would have to completely generate new data from scratch.

Comment: thank this code worked,but im noob in sql server and its pro level

Answer (score 0):

Using cross apply and group by

```
create table #t(
Parent  int,
[date]  date,
currency_type varchar(3),
currency decimal(20,2)
);
insert #t (Parent,[date], currency_type, currency)
values
(4106,'2016/06/11','EUR',3000.00    ),
(2055,'2017/06/10','USD',4000000.00 ),
(2055,'2017/06/10','EUR',4030000.00 )
;


select 
   Parent,[date], c.curr currency_type, max(case currency_type when c.curr then currency else 0 end) currency
from #t t
cross apply(
    select curr
    -- add currencies to the list as needed
    from (values ('EUR'),('USD')) c(curr)
) c
group by Parent,[date], c.curr;
```